# hadoop-streaming : How reduce task calculates reduce input size? and how to fix it?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I see the following in jobtracker log :

```
011-11-02 10:04:09,595 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: No room for reduce task. Node tracker_worker1:localhost/127.0.0.1:52295 has 62087933952 bytes free; but we expect reduce input to take 176511226508
```

- I want to know how hadoop calculated that reducer input to take **176511226508**.
- I have two small worker nodes with 70 gigs each, and one reducer, how can I resolve this issue? `by increasing the number of reducers?`

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982517/hadoop-streaming-resolving-space-issues and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962730/hadoop-streaming-reduce-task-in-pending-state-says-no-room-for-reduce-task

Answer (score 1):

Check the [ResourceEstimator#getEstimatedReduceInputSize()](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.21/mapreduce/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ResourceEstimator.java). As always, the comments around the getEstimatedReduceInputSize function are sparse. Some effort has to be put to understand it.

Comment: Good one, but I don't know if this is available to python streaming api.

Comment: @Thomas - What do you mean by available? AFAIK, this function is invoked by Hadoop before launching the streaming tasks.

Comment: He can't call it from python. It is a java class. But he can calculate it with a calculator ;)